# De Rham cohomology disjoint union of cylinders

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

Could someone explain me (sorry for the, maybe, trivial question :-) ) how to prove that $H^1_{DR}((S^1\times\mathbb{R}) \sqcup(S^1\times\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{R}^2$?

I'm talking about the de Rham cohomology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only the following three facts:

- $H^1(X\sqcup Y) = H^1(X) \oplus H^1(Y)$,
- $H^1 (X\times \mathbb R) = H^1(X)$, and
- $H^1(\mathbb S^1) = \mathbb R$.

The first and the third facts can be proved directly, while the second one (sometimes referred as the Poincare lemma) might be a bit harder to show. Everything are well discussed in the book Differential forms in Algebraic topology by Bott and Tu.

Comment: We could throw in some important names: the second point is called Poincare Lemma, and the third point is a consequence of Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Both are explained in *Differential forms in algebraic topology* by Bott and Tu.

Comment: @Taladris : The third fact can be proved directly without using the Mayer-Vietoris argument.

Comment: I didn't say it was the only way.

Comment: My problem is the first fact. It's not fear to me. While the other two are just consequences of two big theorems

Comment: I think it is always preferred that the easiest method is used? @Taladris (I didn't say you claimed there's only one too ^^)

Comment: MV for De Rham cohomology is quite easy. I would be happy to see an easier method though.

Comment: @avati91 : You can try to show that $\Omega^1(X \sqcup Y) = \Omega^1 (X) \oplus \Omega^1(Y)$

Comment: All one form on $\mathbb S^1$ is represented by $\alpha = f(x) dx$, where $f(x)$ is periodic. Then one can check $\alpha = df $ if and only if $\int f(x) dx = 0$. That's fundamental theorem of calculus essentially. @Taladris

Comment: Ok, I will. Thanks